# How to gather nested object keys to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I convert object keys to an array with different data types? Javascript map function does not cover the object data type values.

Example:

```
let obj = {
  data1: 'test',
  data2: boolean,
  data3: {
    test1: 'test',
    test2: 'test'
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
let arr = [
  'data1',
  'data2',
  'data3.test1',
  'data3.test2'
]
```

Comment: Have you tried `Object.keys(obj)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const listPaths = (obj) => {
  function rKeys(o, path) {
    if (typeof o !== "object") return path;
    return Object.keys(o).map((key) =>
      rKeys(o[key], path ? [path, key].join(".") : key)
    );
  }

  return rKeys(obj).toString().split(",").filter(Boolean);
}

const obj = {
  data1: 'test',
  data2: false,
  data3: {
    test1: 'test',
    test2: 'test'
  }
};

console.log(listPaths(obj));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another potential option is to create a function `transform` to get the entries (a `[[key, val], ...]` array of your object) of your object and map each of those entries to its `key` if the `val`ue isn't an object, otherwise, if the value is an object, you can call the `transform` function again on the inner-object, which will again return an array of keys. You can then use `.map()` on this array of keys to add your current key (that holds the object) as a prefix to the keys from the inner object:

```js
const obj = {
  data1: 'test',
  data2: true,
  data3: {
    test1: 'test',
    test2: {
      example1: 0
    },
    test3: 'test'
  }
};

const transform = (obj) => {
  return Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([key, val]) => 
    Object(val) === val ? transform(val).map(subKey => `${key}.${subKey}`) : key
  );
}

console.log(transform(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive approach to reach deep properties. Feel free to ask questions if something  is quite difficult to understand.

```js
const isArray = hit => Array.isArray(hit)
const isObject = hit => !isArray(hit) && typeof hit === 'object'
const isNonIterable = hit => !isArray(hit) && !isObject(hit)

const toPath = (data, prefix = '') => {
  const store = []

  if (isArray(data)) {
    if (prefix) {
      store.push(prefix)
    }

    store.push(...toPath(data[0], `${prefix}[i]`))
    return store
  }

  if (isObject(data)) {
    if (prefix) {
      store.push(prefix)
    }

    for (const key in data) {
      const currData = data[key]
      const currPrefix = prefix ? `${prefix}.${key}` : key

      if (isNonIterable(currData)) {
        store.push(currPrefix)
      } else {
        store.push(...toPath(currData, currPrefix))
      }
    }

    return store
  }

  return store
}


const data = {
  match: {
    id: 720359,
    play: '2021-12-20 00:30:00',
    score: null,
    status: 'Postponed'
  },
  league: {
    id: 1115,
    kor: '',
    name: 'Norway: Blno'
  },
  home_team: {
    id: 1610,
    kor: '',
    name: 'Tromso'
  },
  away_team: {
    id: 1613,
    kor: '',
    name: 'Avangard Omsk'
  },
  game: {
    id: 3,
    kor: '농구',
    name: 'basketball'
  },
  match_games: [
    {
      type: {
        id: 1,
        div: 'odd',
        kor: '승/무/패',
        name: '3Way Result'
      },
      odds: {
        odd: {
          size: 1,
          Home: 2.95,
          deep: 1,
          stop: 0,
          gap: 1.45,
          Draw: 13,
          Away: 1.5
        }
      },
      score: '[83,60]'
    }
  ]
}

const paths = toPath(data)

console.log(paths)

// [
//   '[i]',
//   '[i].match',
//   '[i].match.id',
//   '[i].match.play',
//   '[i].match.score',
//   '[i].match.status',
//   '[i].league',
//   '[i].league.id',
//   '[i].league.kor',
//   '[i].league.name',
//   '[i].home_team',
//   '[i].home_team.id',
//   '[i].home_team.kor',
//   '[i].home_team.name',
//   '[i].away_team',
//   '[i].away_team.id',
//   '[i].away_team.kor',
//   '[i].away_team.name',
//   '[i].game',
//   '[i].game.id',
//   '[i].game.kor',
//   '[i].game.name',
//   '[i].match_games',
//   '[i].match_games[i]',
//   '[i].match_games[i].type',
//   '[i].match_games[i].type.id',
//   '[i].match_games[i].type.div',
//   '[i].match_games[i].type.kor',
//   '[i].match_games[i].type.name',
//   '[i].match_games[i].odds',
//   '[i].match_games[i].odds.odd',
//   '[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.size',
//   '[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.Home',
//   '[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.deep',
//   '[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.stop',
//   '[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.gap',
//   '[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.Draw',
//   '[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.Away',
//   '[i].match_games[i].score'
// ]
```

Moreover, you can add the data type by just adjust the code a little bit:

```js
const isArray = hit => Array.isArray(hit)
const isObject = hit => !isArray(hit) && typeof hit === 'object'
const isNonIterable = hit => !isArray(hit) && !isObject(hit)
const isBoolean = hit => typeof hit === 'boolean'
const isNumber = hit => typeof hit === 'number' || (!isNaN(Number(hit)) && !isBoolean(hit))
const isString = hit => typeof hit === 'string'
const isDate = hit => new Date(hit).toString() !== 'Invalid Date'

const getType = payload => {
  if (isArray(payload)) {
    return 'array'
  }

  if (isObject(payload)) {
    return 'object'
  }

  if (isNumber(payload)) {
    return 'number'
  }

  if (isDate(payload)) {
    return 'date'
  }

  if (isString(payload)) {
    return 'string'
  }

  if (isBoolean(payload)) {
    return 'boolean'
  }

  if (isBoolean(payload)) {
    return 'boolean'
  }
}

const toPath = (data, prefix = '') => {
  const store = []

  const storeData = (loggerPayload, loggerPrefix) => ({
    path: loggerPrefix,
    type: getType(loggerPayload)
  })

  if (isArray(data)) {
    if (prefix) {
      store.push(storeData(data, prefix))
    }

    store.push(...toPath(data[0], `${prefix}[i]`))
    return store
  }

  if (isObject(data)) {
    if (prefix) {
      store.push(storeData(data, prefix))
    }

    for (const key in data) {
      const currData = data[key]
      const currPrefix = prefix ? `${prefix}.${key}` : key

      isNonIterable(currData)
        ? store.push(storeData(currData, currPrefix))
        : store.push(...toPath(currData, currPrefix))
    }

    return store
  }

  return store
}

const data = [
  {
    match: {
      id: 720359,
      play: '2021-12-20 00:30:00',
      score: null,
      status: 'Postponed'
    },
    league: {
      id: 1115,
      kor: '',
      name: 'Norway: Blno'
    },
    home_team: {
      id: 1610,
      kor: '',
      name: 'Tromso'
    },
    away_team: {
      id: 1613,
      kor: '',
      name: 'Avangard Omsk'
    },
    game: {
      id: 3,
      kor: '농구',
      name: 'basketball'
    },
    match_games: [
      {
        type: {
          id: 1,
          div: 'odd',
          kor: '승/무/패',
          name: '3Way Result'
        },
        odds: {
          odd: {
            size: 1,
            Home: 2.95,
            deep: 1,
            stop: 0,
            gap: 1.45,
            Draw: 13,
            Away: 1.5
          }
        },
        score: '[83,60]'
      }
    ]
  }
]

const paths = toPath(data)

console.log(paths)

// [
//   {
//     "path": "[i]",
//     "type": "object"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match",
//     "type": "object"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match.id",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match.play",
//     "type": "date"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match.score",
//     "type": "object"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match.status",
//     "type": "string"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].league",
//     "type": "object"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].league.id",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].league.kor",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].league.name",
//     "type": "string"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].home_team",
//     "type": "object"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].home_team.id",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].home_team.kor",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].home_team.name",
//     "type": "string"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].away_team",
//     "type": "object"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].away_team.id",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].away_team.kor",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].away_team.name",
//     "type": "string"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].game",
//     "type": "object"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].game.id",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].game.kor",
//     "type": "string"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].game.name",
//     "type": "string"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games",
//     "type": "array"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i]",
//     "type": "object"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].type",
//     "type": "object"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].type.id",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].type.div",
//     "type": "string"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].type.kor",
//     "type": "string"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].type.name",
//     "type": "string"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].odds",
//     "type": "object"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].odds.odd",
//     "type": "object"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.size",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.Home",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.deep",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.stop",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.gap",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.Draw",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].odds.odd.Away",
//     "type": "number"
//   },
//   {
//     "path": "[i].match_games[i].score",
//     "type": "string"
//   }
// ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a recursive function that takes the object's entries, and iterates them with `Array.flatMap()`. Concat the current key to the previous one. If the current value is an object, call the function again, and pass the value, and the current key. If not return the current key.

This will work for multiple levels of nested objects.

```js
const listPaths = (obj, init) => Object.entries(obj)
  .flatMap(([k, v]) => {
    const key = init ? `${init}.${k}` : k
    
    return typeof v === 'object' ? listPaths(v, key) : key
  })
 
const obj = {
  data1: 'test',
  data2: false,
  data3: {
    test1: 'test',
    test2: 'test',
    data3: {
      'sub-test1': 'sub-test',
      'sub-test2': 'sub-test'
    }
  }
}

const result = listPaths(obj)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating a function, say `getKeys()` that will traverse the object recursively, returning keys in the form 'a.b.c' once each leaf item is hit.

```js
let obj = {
  data1: 'test',
  data2: true,
  data3: {
    test1: 'test',
    test2: 'test'
  }
}

function getKeys(obj, path = []) {
    let keys = [];
    // We've hit a 'leaf' in the object tree, return the path.
    if (!obj || typeof(obj) !== 'object') return [ path.join('.') ];
    // Call recursively for each child object...
    for(let k in obj) {
        keys = [...keys, ...getKeys(obj[k], [...path, k])];
    } 
    return keys;
}

console.log(getKeys(obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have mentioned, recursion can be used in this case.

Following is another implementation that I find easy to understand. It uses [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), [Array.Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), and can handle any hierarchy depth.

```js
function getKeys(obj) {
 let keys = [];
 for(const prop in obj){
   if (typeof obj[prop] === "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[prop])) {
     let subKeys = getKeys(obj[prop]);
     subKeys = subKeys.map(ele => `${prop}.${ele}`);
     keys = [...keys, ...subKeys];
   } else {
     keys = [...keys, prop];
   }
 }
 return keys;
}

let ob = {
  data1: 'test',
  data2: true,
  data3: {
    test1: 'test',
    test2: 'test',
    data4: {
      hello: 1
    }
  }
}

console.log(getKeys(ob));
```